# Increase RGB components every Hour (r), Minute (g), Second (b) for digital clock

Tags: javascript, clock

So I am taking my first javascript class (total noob) and one of the assignments is to modify a digital clock by assigning the color red to hours, green minutes, blue to seconds, then increase the respective color component when it changes. I have successfully assigned a decimal color value (ex. "#850000" to each element (hours, minutes, seconds), but my brain is fried trying to figure out how to increase the brightness when hours, minutes, seconds change, i.e. red goes up to "#870000" changing from 1:00:00 pm to 2:00:00 pm. I've searched everywhere with no help on how to successfully do this. Here is what I have so far and any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

TJ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function updateClock()
    {

      var currentTime = new Date();
      var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
      var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
      var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

      // Pad the minutes with leading zeros, if required 
      currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;

      // Pad the seconds with leading zeros, if required 
      currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

      // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
      var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

      // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format
      currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

      // Convert an hours component if "0" to "12"
      currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

        // Get hold of the html elements by their ids
        var hoursElement = document.getElementById("hours");
        document.getElementById("hours").style.color = "#850000";
        var minutesElement = document.getElementById("minutes");
        document.getElementById("minutes").style.color = "#008500";
        var secondsElement = document.getElementById("seconds");
        document.getElementById("seconds").style.color = "#000085";
        var am_pmElement = document.getElementById("am_pm");

        // Put the clock sections text into the elements' innerHTML
        hoursElement.innerHTML = currentHours;
        minutesElement.innerHTML = currentMinutes;
        secondsElement.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
        am_pmElement.innerHTML = timeOfDay;
    }               
// -->
</script>

</head>
<body onload="updateClock(); setInterval( 'updateClock()', 1000 )">
    <h1 align="center">The JavaScript digital clock</h1>
    <h2 align="center">Thomas Fertterer - Lab 2</h2>
    <div id='clock' style="text-align: center">
        <span id="hours"></span>:
        <span id='minutes'></span>:
        <span id='seconds'></span>
        <span id='am_pm'></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some what related: http://collegesnippets.blogspot.com/2011/09/time-color.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use `rgb` colors. They're somewhat easier to work with, as you can represent the color channels' values with integers:

```
document.getElementById("hours").style.color = 'rgb(100, 200, 300)';
```

Here's a helper function for you. It takes in numerical rgb values and returns a string:

```
function rgb(r, g, b) {
    return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}
```

Example:

```
> rgb(1, 2, 3)
"rgb(1, 2, 3)"
```

Also, I'd advise against using string arguments for `setInterval`:

```
setInterval( 'updateClock()', 1000 )
```

Just use a reference to the function instead:

```
setInterval(updateClock, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar project I worked, I used `Math.sin` function to have the red, blue, and green components fluctuate based on the current time.  Depending on how exactly you want to the colors to change, you can modify the following example code:

```
setInterval(function () {
   var currentTime = new Date()
 var red = Math.floor( (Math.sin(+currentTime/100000)+1) * 255/2);
   var blue = Math.floor( (Math.sin(2 * (+currentTime/100000 + 50))+1) * 255/2);
   var green = Math.floor( (Math.sin(3 * (+currentTime/100000 + 170))+1) * 255/2);

   var color = "rgba(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ",255)";
   document.getElementById('clock').style.color = color;
}, 100);
```

A full example can be seen [here](http://collegesnippets.blogspot.com/2011/09/time-color.html).

In your case, I would modify the code to have the red, blue, and green components solely depend on the hour, minute, and second components of the `Date();`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the below changes where you assign the color to the hours part:

```
document.getElementById("hours").style.color = "rgb(" + (135 + (5 * currentHours)) + ",0,0)";
```

Comment: Thanks very much Rups, this worked perfectly. I just changed red, green, and blue to reflect the currentHours, currentMinutes, and currentSeconds and everything is golden. Even resets to the base starting color I set everything to when each time interval starts over. Thanks again.